# JS FullCalendar V4 Right Click Menu - Selected Dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

(V4)Im attempting to add a right click menu to my calendar which will allow user to perform other operations with events.

I am needing to figure out how to get the selected dates values displayed in my `alert()` so that can assign variables to those dates and create events.

First I have disabled the default menu with this:

```
$("#calendar").on("contextmenu",function (event) {event.preventDefault();});
```

Next I have created an event for the right click:

```
jQuery(document.body).on("mousedown", function(event){
    if(event.button==2){
        alert();
    }
});
```

The `selectable` value in my calendar is set to `true`.

How would I get the selected date values in my `alert()`

**EDIT** I have tried `alert(calendar.selectionInfo)` but it was `undefined`

**EDIT 2** my html for the calendar

```
<link href='vendor/fullcalendar/core/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='vendor/fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='vendor/fullcalendar/timegrid/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<div id="calendar"></div>
<script src="./vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="./vendor/fullcalendar/core/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="./vendor/fullcalendar/daygrid/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="./vendor/fullcalendar/timegrid/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="./vendor/fullcalendar/interaction/main.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT 3** some changes to my code

```
$("#calendar").on("mousedown", function(event){
    if(event.button==2){
        alert(calendar.selectionInfo);
    }
});
```

Comment: can you post the html of your calendar ?

Comment: @Gui3 see edit please

Answer (score 1):

it seems what you want isn't easy...

the FullCalendar API provides something close :
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dateClick

with this **option you pass when creating the calendar** you can decide what happens when user clicks on a date, but I assume it is left-clicking only

for example display the date in an alert :

```js
let calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
  plugins: [ interactionPlugin ],
  dateClick: function(info) {
    alert('Clicked on: ' + info.dateStr);
  }
});
```

If you really want right-clicking, I'm trying another solution but it will not be clean code ... updating soon

---

**Edit**

I found something that works but it's not clean and you will soon be limited...

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".fc-day").forEach(
  element => element.addEventListener(
    "contextmenu",
     event => { 
        event.preventDefault(); 
        event.stopPropagation();
        alert(event.target.dataset.date); //here you have the date of the cell
     }
  )
);
```

Comment: Hi any one please update on this as I need right click menu like contect menu as in https://jsfiddle.net/p52gohwn/ , but it's not working in 4.0 version.